# C++ Debugging "smell"

Tags: c++, debugging, destructor, virtual-functions

I was debugging an odd problem where an objects VMT suddenly seemed to point to the base object's methods.

```
class Base
{ 
  virtual void foo() {}
}

class Derived: public Base
{ 
  void foo() {}
}

Derived * d =  new Derived;

... much complex fettling ...

d->foo(); // Help! called Base::foo()!!!
```

It turned that a bug in the 'complex' code was effectively doing `delete d;`. I won't go into details except to say that `boost::noncopyable` is your friend, and never under ANY circumstances roll your own smart pointer classes.

But, my question is this - is this kind of alteration of the VMT a good 'smell' that you are dealing with a deleted object? I guess that the VMT gets 'unrolled' back to `Base` during destruction?

Obviously this is horribly implmentation dependent, and I was 'lucky' that the memory hadn't been trampled on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what the question is – but I’d say that this:

> I was 'lucky' that the memory hadn't been trampled on...

is wrong: you weren’t lucky – you were *un*lucky. Had the memory been trampled on during deletion, you would probably had the code crash much closer to the actual problem and the error would have been much clearer.

Code that fails should fail as early as possible so as to give a hint about the failure location.

Comment: Agreed. I would love `delete` to set the pointer to NULL automagically.

Comment: @Roddy unfortunately that would be of limited use since there may be other pointers referring to the same object. Ideally, all these would be set to null but that would of course entail tracking all pointers, which C++ doesn’t do for performance reasons.

Comment: true, but I'd still like it. Just because one can't address every situation shouldn't prevent you from improving the common ones.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for g++, for which the vtable alteration you observed is in fact what happens. You can sometimes use this to determine that a pointer's object was deleted but that doesn't usually help a lot, since deletions may occur in more than one place. `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are your friends to manage memory.

Answer (score 0):

You were lucky that you got the base class behavior rather than a segfault.

If you're mucking with a deleted object, the behavior is undefined.